# Can android AVD emulator run within VMWare?

Tags: android-emulator, virtualization, vmware

Hi I am running Windows 8 in VMWare Workstation 9 and I wanted to setup an android development environment, I installed Java the ADK and Android studio. When I create an AVD and try to start it it appears as a black screen with buttons pane. I think the problem is that I can't run an emulator within another emulator, but I just wanted to check in case anyone else has been successful.

The errors it shows are:
Failed to create pbuf surface for FB 0x3004
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
extension WGL_ARB_make_current_read was not found extension WGL_EXT_swap_control was not found

I had difficulty searching for this because the results tend to be people trying to setup an android VM as a standalone, rather than running android development emulator in a Windows 8 VM like my setup.

Comment: Why are you doing it all in an emulator anyway? The Android development tools also run on MacOS and GNU/Linux.

Comment: I just wanted a separate place for my android development stuff that would be portable from my desktop. I just tried installing Android dev kit and JDK and to run the AVD emulator on my desktop outside VMWare and still had a black screen occur. I installed HAXM and it still wouldnt run. I found that if I choose "no skin" the emulator finally ran, but extremely slowly. I'm looking at setting up a dedicated android x86 VM because the emulator seems pretty bad based on this experience.

Comment: Using two separate VMs would be just as portable (copying 2 folders instead of one is not a big deal) and eliminate the issues of trying to do virtualization under virtualization.

Answer (score 2):

I've been able to run it in Windows 8.1 Pro within VM Ware 10. This was when I was used ADT though for eclipse. When I switched over to Android Studio I haven't been able to get a AVM to start yet. Granted I've spent about 30 minutes working on it, so I haven't exhausted all options just yet.

I imagine speed will always be an issue though. While the overhead for windows within VW Ware Workstation is sleight given the shared architecture it's enough to introduce some slow downs. Still for the most part I've been able to use the AVM for my purposes. (Really just making sure the app can start and doesn't crash) from there I put it on a real device.